# Limiting SSH root logins to only "safe" networks in OpenSSH 4.x

Tags: linux, security, ssh, redhat, pam

We want to limit `root` SSH login to only a few networks that we consider "safe" (VPN, etc.) without imposing the same condition on other accounts.

In OpenSSH 5.x, we could use the `match` block. However, that is not an option in OpenSSH 4.x which is what we are limited to in RHEL5.

I was thinking perhaps this could be done using PAM. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding this [Cyberciti.biz article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/openssh-root-user-account-restriction-revisited.html), I started looking into `pam_access`. This is the solution I am settling on:

First, I created an access file in `/etc/security/sshd.conf`. I chose doing this instead of using the default `/etc/security/access.conf` because I wanted an access file dedicated to `sshd`. The file looks like this:

```
# cat /etc/security/sshd.conf
+:root:192.168.0.0/8
-:root:ALL
```

Check out `man access.conf` for more information on syntax.

Then, I added the following line on top of the PAM stack in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
auth       required     pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/sshd.conf
```

The reason I used `auth` instead of `account` as done in the Cyberciti.biz article was because using `account` type allowed users to verify the password and *then* get rejected. I rather not verify the password. Check out `man pam.conf` for more information.

This worked perfectly.

Comment: Answering your own question is a good thing.  Please consider updating it with more detail when you test this and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pam_access will do that. Other possibilities include tcp wrappers (RHEL5 sshd supports them) and iptables.

Comment: I was under the impression that `tcpwrappers` will not be able to distinguish user, is that incorrect? I only want this condition to apply to root account.

Comment: Didn't consider you'd need this for `root`-only, sorry.

Comment: NP, I added some text to the question to make it clear. Thank you both though!

Comment: Sorry, I failed at reading comprehension. :(

Answer (score 0):

No experience with RHEL and friends, but I'd probably try to use tcpwrappers first -- I mean the `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files:

```
---8<--- hosts.deny ---8<---     
ALL: ALL
```

and

```
---8<--- hosts.allow ---8<---
ALL: localhost, 10.y.z.
```

Notice the implied /24; I'm not sure about the syntax for CIDR-blocks. If you need it I can hunt it up. Try to avoid locking yourself out using these tricks.

PS: You have considered ARP spoofing, right?